Replace 0s with a number left padded with 0s
I'm working on a project which will keep track of files with an automatically generated number. However, I need the user to be able to specify the format for this number. For example, if I have a format string file-000000#-v000a, the first part of the number should always be a minimum of 6 digits long, and the second should be a minimum of 3 digits long, left padded with 0s, like: file-000128-001, but if they have more or less 0s, it should adjust accordingly.
I've tried to come up with something using the String.prototype.replace() function, but I'm not sure how to calculate the leftPadding so that it's the correct number of 0s.
Here's what I've tried so far:


let file_counter = 128;
let version_counter = 1;

// not sure how to calculate these numbers
let leftPadding = 6;
let leftPadding2 = 3;

const format = 'file-000000#-v000a';
const number = format
                .replace(/0+#/, file_counter.toString().padStart(leftPadding, '0'))
                .replace(/0+a/, version_counter.toString().padStart(leftPadding2, '0'));

console.log(number);




The format doesn't really make sense. Can you find another way to express it, e.g. just "000000"?

I need it to end in another character (letter or otherwise) because there will be a couple different numbers, and the user needs to be able to choose which one to use

I have since found an answer to this, so if anyone comes looking for something similar, here it is:


const format = 'file-000000#-v000a';
const val1 = `${128}`;
const val2 = `${1}`;

let number = replaceValue(format, /0*#/g, val1);
number = replaceValue(number, /0*a/g, val2);

console.log(number);

function replaceValue(format, regex, value) {
    const matches = [];
    let m;
    do {
        m = regex.exec(format)
        if (m)
            matches.push({
                str: m[0],
                index: m.index
            })
    } while (m);

    for (let match of matches) {
        format = format.replace(match.str, value.padStart(match.str.length - 1, '0'));
    }

    return format;
}



A little explanation:
In the replaceValue() function, I find all places where the regex is being found, and then I go through each one and replace it with the provided value.

This is my solution:


const format = "file-000000#-v000a",
  val1 = `${128}`,
  val2 = `${1}`;

const helper = (str, val, len) => str.replace(/0+/, val.padStart(len, "0"));

var parts = format.split("-");

parts[1] = helper(parts[1], val1, 6);

parts[2] = helper(parts[2], val2, 3);

var whole = parts.join("-");

console.log(whole);




It's a good idea, but I can't rely on the - for splitting and joining. Since the user can specify any format string they want, it might not always have -s separating the different parts

You can create a simple function accepting the splitting character as an argument.

What about in the case when there is no splitting character? If I split by every character, then I would end up with a fixed length of 0s in front of the numbers

In that case (I assume you mean e.g. "file000000#v000a"), you don't need to split by every character: just use match with a regular expression. But this is what you can do even if the format includes a splitting character. https://regex101.com/
